# Recorded my computer screen with Windows Game Bar when a power outage occured. How do I recover the file?

Tags: windows, windows-10, file-recovery, file-corruption, screen-recorder

I recorded a Zoom meeting with the Windows game bar when my home had a power outage. I turned my computer back on, and found the MP4 of the recording sitting in the recordings folder. The file is almost 2GB so I'd assume the data is still there, it's just that Windows didn't stop writing the file correctly, and when I try to open it the windows video player tells me the file format isn't supported or the file is corrupt. How do I restore the file? This recording is important to me.

Comment: What do you mean "restore"? You said that the file is there. Does it not play correctly?

Comment: You're right, I didn't specify what the problem with it is. Added it in.

Comment: Without understanding the reason the file is incomplete, which at this point only someone with access to the file could determine, it's impossible to say how to "fix" the file so it can be played.  The ultimate conclusion likely will be that the file is corrupt and it cannot be fixed.

Comment: [I suspect you would have better luck if you used Zoom to record meetings in the future.](https://support.zoom.us/hc/en-us/articles/201362473-Enabling-and-starting-local-recordings)

Answer (score 0):

It's impossible to answer without looking at the actual file, other than suggesting you try some of the available tools:

- WonderShare makes a video repair tool
- Stellar has a video repair tool
- Online services, fix.video and restore.media. For repairing a single file these are often cheaper than the tools above.

What all these have in common is that they will request a reference or sample file, so simply create a small video with the tool that was used to create the corrupt video.

Most common issue is, assuming MP4 that the moov atom wasn't created or referenced to. This atom is like the index of the file that is created last once all actual video data (mdat atom) is written to the file. It's basically an array of pointers to video chunks.

[image: moov atom pointing to video data]